# How to create modern team site with connected to the Office 365 group using SharePoint online management shell

Tags: powershell, templates, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, teamsite

How to get template ID for the Office 365 group team site in SharePoint Online using SharePoint Online management shell?

Here, I have a SharePoint Team site, Now I would like to know the site template ID using PowerShell Script. I don't have any clue to get the site template ID.

To resolve this issue, give me any suggestions...

Comment: Do you want to do this using SPO PowerShell only? Is using [PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) allowed for you? It is easier to perform such operations using PnP PowerShell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Get-SPOSite` command which will return the site template ID of your SharePoint site:

```
Get-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/groupname -detailed
```

**Documentation**: [Get-SPOSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-sposite?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

`GROUP#0` is the template ID for SharePoint team sites connected with M365 groups.

**Related read**: [SharePoint Online Site Template ID list for PowerShell](https://vladtalkstech.com/2019/12/sharepoint-online-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html).